Use Wine and PyInstaller to Create Windows Executables
I am setting up a CI/CD pipeline on Gitlab for creating executables through PyInstaller for Windows, Mac, and Linux. I have Mac and Linux down, but since PyInstaller can't cross-compile, I am using Wine through an Ubuntu image to try and create my executables. Here is my windows job:
build-windows:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - apt-get -y update
    - apt-get -y install sudo
    - apt-get install -y wine-stable  wget
    - sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
    - apt-get -y update
    - apt-get -y install wine32:i386
    - wget -O python-installer.exe https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.9/python-3.8.9-amd64.exe
    - wine python-installer.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 TargetDir=/root/.wine/drive_c/Python
    - wine /root/.wine/drive_c/Python/python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
    - wine /root/.wine/drive_c/Python/python.exe -m pip install pyinstaller
    - wine /root/.wine/drive_c/Python/python.exe -m pip install -r requirements.txt
  image: ubuntu:latest
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 month
    name: "$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_TAG-windows"
    paths:
      - dist/  #  $CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_TAG-windows
  # only:
    # - tags
  script:
    - wine /root/.wine/drive_c/Python/python.exe -m pyinstaller --onefile python.py --name ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_TAG}-windows

Here is what I run into when running the pipeline:
2024-05-21 23:21:02 (207 MB/s) - 'python-installer.exe' saved [28233448/28233448]
$ wine python-installer.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 TargetDir=/root/.wine/drive_c/Python
wine: created the configuration directory '/root/.wine'
004c:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
004c:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow L"The explorer process failed to start."
004c:err:systray:initialize_systray Could not create tray window
004c:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hr 0x80004002
004c:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, hr 0x80004002
004c:err:ole:apartment_get_local_server_stream Failed: 0x80004002
0044:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0044:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow L"Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly."
0054:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0054:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow L"Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly."
0054:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 3
0054:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
0054:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 14007
0054:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hr 0x800736b7
0054:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, hr 0x800736b7
0054:err:ole:apartment_get_local_server_stream Failed: 0x800736b7
0054:err:ole:start_rpcss Failed to open RpcSs service
002c:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
002c:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow L"Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly."
0090:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0090:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow L"Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly."
00e0:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
00e0:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow L"Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly."
wine: configuration in L"/root/.wine" has been updated.
0144:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0144:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow L"Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly."
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1

As you can see, the python setup.exe downloads perfectly fine, but when I try running it, it gives me errors relating to UI. Since this is all CLI, I obviously can't interact with a UI. I have what I think are the correct parameters to ignore UI and install quietly. Initially, I was getting an issue telling me that I did not have wine32 installed, and I added the correct packages listed in the error message, but that did not fix it at all.
